# Unable to open PDF in Web App. Throwing error in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: document-library

In the SharePoint document library if I directly click on PDF link it is throwing error. But if I click on ... and then open option it is opening.

Comment: Error Message: Sorry, Web app ran into a problem opening this PDF. To view this PDF Please open it in Microsoft Word

Comment: is it SPO or on primise ?

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache in “d” folder on “C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\OfficeWebApps\Working\d” location in **Office Web App server** (drive is dependent.

In my case it is C:\ If you didn’t find ProgramData, you have set folder option to show the hidden files.)

Go the folder location and remove all the files in the folder (or back up all the files instead of deleting).